# How to safely delete relation entity endpoint revisions (field_revision_endpoints)

Tags: 7, entities

I would like to safely clean duplicate field revision data. This field_revision_(field_name) data not associated with nodes, but the relation entities.

I'm using the relation module. I'm bumping up against the problem outlined here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1530164

I have a lot of relations on my site linking different entities. My field_revision_endpoints table is growing quite large. The issue mentions as a work around, he uses a sql script to clear out the old revisions. I did some googling on info for deleting revisions, but I'll I have come up with is results relating to deleting node revisions.

Is it safe to simply delete rows out of field_revision_endpoints?

Comment: How about using [Field SQL norevisions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_sql_norevisions)?

Comment: @pierostz: this looks promising, thanks! I'll give it a try and let you know if it works out for my situation. Maybe you could post it as an answer?

Comment: I am using it myself for the same reasons. Didn't have a problem until now.

Comment: You are using it specifically to reduce the size of field_revision_endpoint? What problem have you run into?

Comment: Other revision tables growing big and shared hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. I eventually had to circle back to this question and come up with a solution myself. The `relation_revision` table contains the relation + revision ids that match up to the `field_revision_endpoints` rows. Simply deleting rows from `relation_revision` would orphan the revision field data in `field_revision_endpoint`.

After poking around the relations issue queue, I found this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation/issues/2925111) which adds support for the Entity API's revision deletion mechanism.

Instead of patching the relations module, I used `hook_entity_info_alter` to register my own [`'revision deletion callback'`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/entity_metadata_hook_entity_info/7) on the relation entity, which I based on the above patch and `node_revision_delete()`. I can now use the Entity API's [`entity_revision_delete()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21entity.module/function/entity_revision_delete/7) to cleanly remove the excess revisions in batches.